# Image squeeze in react parallax component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-parallax

I am working on React 18 and have implemented reusable react component that implements `parallax` using `react-parallax`. this is all working fine but my image is squeeze and messed up ratio when reduce screen size. I have applied css but it seems not working.

[image]

`ParallaxItem`

```
import React from "react";
import { Parallax } from "react-parallax";

const ParallaxItem = ({ imageUrl, strength, imageHeight }) =>{

 const parallaxImageStyle = {
   width: "100%",
   height: imageHeight,
 };

return(
 <div>
  <Parallax bgImage={imageUrl} strength={strength} className="parallax-image-container">
  <div className="parallax-image-container" style={parallaxImageStyle}>
  </div>
 </Parallax>
</div>
 )
}

export default ParallaxItem;
```

`Component using ParallaxItem`

```
import React from "react";
import ParallaxItem from "../../UI/Parallax/ParallaxItem";

const MyPageParallax = () => {
  return (
    <ParallaxItem imageUrl={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/Airport-service.jpg`} strength={500} imageHeight={500}/>
 );
};

export default MyPageParallax;
```

`Using Service`

```
const AirportService = () => {

return (
 <Fragment>
  <LayoutOne>
    <MyPageParallax/>
  </LayoutOne>
 </Fragment>
 );
};
```

`css`

```
 .parallax-image-container {
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on something similar today and faced the same problem. So I went to look at the documentation for [react-parrallex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-parallax).

This is what solved the problem for me. By customizing the image style in the **bgImageStyle** props. Your code will look like this.

```
<Parallax bgImageStyle={{ width: "100%", height:'fit-content' }} bgImage={imageUrl} strength={strength} className="parallax-image-container">
```

This should make the image scale across the width of your screen nicely. I hope this helps.